# onDeleted method not firing up when appwidget is deleted

Tags: android, android-appwidget

The `onDeleted` method is not firing when an appwidget is deleted from the home screen.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a somewhat common problem with Android widgets.

If you are subclassing AppWidgetProvider, onDelete() is liable not to get called. In order to work around this, you can instead implement the onReceive() method and explicitly look for APPWIDGET_DELETED.

References:
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Nl0e06rDCRY
- http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/06/03/writing-an-android-widget-what-the-docs-dont-tell-you/