# onDeleted, onDisabled are not being called at all when removing an android widget

Tags: android, widget, lifecycle

Seems this has been a pain for some time now (did quite a bit of research in SO and on the net)

In a nutshell the android documentation states:

- onReceive will be called before every other lifecycle method calls
- onDeleted will be called when a widget is removed
- onDisabled will be called when the last widget is deleted

Well, when deleting a widget neither onReceive nor subsequently onDeleted is being called. Similarly, when the last widget is removed the code does not reach to onDisabled either.

**1. This has been an issue since android version 1.5 and continues to be up to now.**

**Android developers at Google, what was the reason of not fixing this after over 10 major releases?**

To everybody else...

Is there any workaround for this regardless how ugly it might be?

Excuse my frustrated tone.

Comment: It seems there is a workaround as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385780/ondeleted-method-not-firing-up-when-appwidget-is-deleted

Comment: Thank you @etienne. I caught that too. Still, Google needs to fix it.

Comment: On a HTC Flyer not even the onReceive() method is called when the widget is deleted. So no workaround for the Flyer...