# onDisabled and onDeleted method not being called

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

For some reason, the onDisabled and onDeleted method of my widget is not getting called when i remove the widget from the homescreen. I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
public class WidgetProvider2x1 extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    Log.i("MyTag", "onEnabled");

    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.i("MyTag", "onDeleted");
    Toast.makeText(context, "onDeleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {

     Log.i("MyTag", "onDisabled");
     Toast.makeText(context, "onDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     super.onDisabled(context);
}
```

LogCat also does not show anything.

Comment: It seems there is a workaround as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385780/ondeleted-method-not-firing-up-when-appwidget-is-deleted

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the link is not working for me. No intent is received in onReceive when widget is removed from the homescreen. This is bad :(    Is there any other way to detect widget removed?   Thanks btw.